# Element is not clickable at this point while other elements would receive the click

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[image]

How can I resolve this issue? I post HTML code and exception

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the application at the moment of the exception? And your code?

Comment: Add which error you caught after your tests execution.

Comment: Please show us your actual test automation code

Comment: Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/section[2]/form/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/input[2]"))).click().build().perform();

Comment: This is my automation code

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is telling you that another element is overlaying the one you want to click on. Check the screenshot, identify what is covering it. You may need to add some other interaction to uncover your element.

Answer (score 0):

I get around this by clicking via JavaScript. Here is my code in C#:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `find` on the element first.
You could also try adding an explicit wait for the element.

See if those help.